# how is it possible that using wp_insert_category throw a fatal error?

Tags: terms

how is it possible that using wp_insert_category throw a fatal error ?

I am using it as explained : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category
with no change except:

```
$cat_defaults = array(
    'cat_name' => 'some_name',
    'category_description' => 'as asdfasdf sdf adfa fas f',
    'category_nicename' => '',
    'category_parent' => '',
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
 );
$someSome = wp_insert_category($cat_defaults);
```

i dont know if its relevant however i execute it on `add_action( 'init', array($this, 'registerCustoms') );`

And i get the following error :

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_insert_category() in /home1/stodeckc/public_html/podio-wp-sync/wp-content/plugins/podio_management/libs/appSync/appSync_custom.php on line 61`

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question has already been answered possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170554/wordpress-error-call-to-undefined-function-in-plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `init` action is the wrong place. This is because `init` runs on all requests, admin or front-end, but the `wp_insert_category` function is an admin-side only function. You generally don't insert categories from the front end.

Move to a more specific action, one that will be run in the admin side. Probably from your plugin's admin pages.

Comment: I do however need to create it not as an admin - i am adding the category as a response to an API response.

Comment: Well i took it out of init and set it in the main scope (out side of my plugin class) and still it did not find it, i ended up using wp_insert_term which seems to work

Answer (score 9):

If you used `wp_insert_category` on Front, you must add this:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php');
```

Comment: It's also good to check if the function exists first:

`if( !function_exists('wp_insert_category') ){ require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php'); }`

Answer (score 5):

you have to use hook admin init

```
function _CreateCategory(){
$my_cat = array('cat_name' => 'Newcategory', 
    'category_description' => 'Descrip',
     'category_nicename' => 'cat-slug',
      'category_parent' => '');

// Create the category
wp_insert_category($my_cat);
}
add_action('admin_init','_CreateCategory');
```

And that's it

Comment: A little explanation of why it must be done in `admin_init` action hook would be great.

Comment: Did you try it, without admin_init?

Comment: I know why it must be used on `admin_init` (or any other later action hook) but I'm not asking for the explanation for myself but for any other reader thay may not know why this code work and the other not. That would make your answer a *great* answer and not only a *working* answer. Answers consisting only in code are not considered good answers here. Please, read the [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) and [How do I write a good answer?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). That is why, as it is, your answer is badder than the current accepted answer.

Comment: Exactly, if you you really want to use wp_insert category and use admin_iti else  wp_insert_term is the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is not required to admin_init, because this also define on taxonomy.php

So please use on this way:

```
require_once('wp-load.php' );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php');

$cat_defaults = array(
    'cat_name' => 'some_name',
    'category_description' => 'as asdfasdf sdf adfa fas f',
    'category_nicename' => '',
    'category_parent' => '',
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
 );
$someSome = wp_insert_category($cat_defaults);
```

Comment: You might want to at least load `wp-load.php` from within an _absolute_ path, like you loaded `taxonomy.php`. And btw, there are other constants for that, that take into account if you moved `wp-admin` to a different location.